# How do you achieve a dynamic mansory layout grid?

Tags: css, vue.js

[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DP8X1.jpg)
I'm trying to achieve the layout in the image with dynamic data using the unsplash API. While I understand how this can be done if the data were static, I was wondering if there was a way to achieve it with dynamic data ?
I'm using vue (if necessary) but I'm really after the css solution to this

Comment: With a bit of Google I found this: https://css-tricks.com/piecing-together-approaches-for-a-css-masonry-layout/. You can't do it natively in CSS. If you want a Vue solution, I found this in Google: https://www.npmjs.com/package/vue-masonry

Comment: I don't know if I get your problem but you can set your data after initliaze? https://masonry.desandro.com/methods.html#jquery-fn-data-masonry

Comment: I had the same issue for the same type of build, the unsplash API :D. I ended up using react-masonry, an npm module to suit myself